# Regular expression to extract text between \()

Tags: regex

I have a string on the following format:

`abc\(def\(ghj)klm)nop\(qrs)tuvw\(xyz\(abc\(def)ghi)jkl)mno)pqr)\(stu)`

[image]

My current regex is :

```
(\\\((?:\[??[^\"\n]*?\)))
```

and it is give me the output in the image, how can I update this regex to achieve the expectation

Comment: Regex aren't suited to parse tree-hierarchy structures. Although this *may* be possible, you'll end up with a complicated RegEx hard to maintain and easy to break

Comment: Sounds way easier to match the number of `\(` with the number of `)` using a *good old loop*

Comment: I second the loop approach. What language do you use? If regex, how many levels deep? If, say max 3 levels, you could build a longer regex that first matches for 3 levels, then 2 levels, then 1 level.

Answer (score 1):

[Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) can helps you with that:

`\\\(([^()]|(?R))*\)`

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/dO0t10/1)

Comment: Thank you!! I use Swift language and it seems not support Recursion with regex.

Answer (score 1):

There are regex dialects that support recursions, namely Perl 5.10, PCRE 4.0, Ruby 2.0. You can match your string with a regex engine that supports recursion as @Vladimir Trifonov pointed out in his answer.

If your regex engine does not support recursion you can match without recursion by building a longer regex that supports up to a max level of nesting, here using your input string as an example:

- max 1 level:  `/(\\\([^\)]*\))/g`

  - match: `["\(def\(ghj)", "\(qrs)", "\(xyz\(abc\(def)", "\(stu)"]`
- max 2 levels:  `/(\\\((?:[^\\\)]*\\\([^\)]*\))?[^\)]*\))/g`

  - match: `["\(def\(ghj)klm)", "\(qrs)", "\(xyz\(abc\(def)ghi)", "\(stu)"]`
- max 3 levels:  `/(\\\((?:[^\\\)]*\\\((?:[^\\\)]*\\\([^\)]*\))?[^\)]*\))?[^\)]*\))/g`

  - match: `["\(def\(ghj)klm)", "\(qrs)", "\(xyz\(abc\(def)ghi)jkl)", "\(stu)"]`
- etc.

In other words, you can increase the max level by nesting `(?:[^\\\)]*\\\(` ... `[^\)]*\))?` patterns; they are made optional with `?`.

**EDIT:**
In case you need to support unlimited nesting and your regex engine does not support recursion, you can use a series of regexes. See JavaScript example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66558399/7475450 and Perl example at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3

Comment: Thank you!! I use Swift language and it seems not support Recursion with regex. the problem is that there is no max number for level.

Comment: @HassanTaleb: YW. In this case how about rinse & repeating that nesting to, say, 10 levels, and document that as a limitation?

Comment: I use this regex for highlighting syntax in an editor that I created. So since user can write any syntax I can't limit levels.

Comment: @HassanTaleb: You could expand that regex to a level that is unlikely to be reached, like 20. Alternatively, see **EDIT** in my answer.

Comment: @HassanTaleb: Any questions? Did you find a solution?